# How to explode string in pair, two key by slice in PHP

Tags: php, explode, implode

```
$myvar1 = 'this car is most new and fast';
$myvar2 = explode(' ', $myvar1);  // slice on spaces
$myvar3 = implode( ',', $myvar2); //add comman
echo $myvar3;
```

output = this, car, is, most, new, and, fast

But I need this output = this car, is most, new and, fast

I need in pair output.

Thanks all.

Comment: Then you are going to have to write some code to do this. No built in functions are going to do it for you

Comment: more of a custom requirement. From the look of your string, you add a `comma` after two words. `substr()` should also help

Comment: @hercules, Hey, I have gotta solution for you! look the answer.

Comment: @Akintunde  I have no idea how to apply substr to make this definition of how many keys will be inserted between the commas, could you write something?   .... Ok  Shaunak Shukla  I will to test now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myvar1 = 'this car is most new and fast';
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z0-9\.]+(?: [A-Za-z0-9\.]+)?)/',
       $myvar1,$myvar2); // splits string on every other space
$myvar3 = implode( ',', $myvar2[0]); //add comman
echo $myvar3;
```

Instead of `explode()`, I have used `preg_match_all(`) to split the string and `implode()` with ','
And here is your output:

> this car,is most,new and,fast

Comment: Thanks alot by your help! yes! your solution has worked too!!

Comment: Thanks! This solution has some limit. A non-alphanumeric character can break the output. So you have to put regex accordingly at that time.

Comment: This limitation has been discussed long before, so I use a lot of regex in this algorithm(no non-alpha), I already have several regex solutions in this variable at a time long before your code, at the beginning of my algorithm :-) I thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$str = 'this car is most new and fast';
$str_explode = explode(' ', $str);
$str_result = '';
$comma = false;

foreach($str_explode AS $word) {
    $str_result .= $word;

    if($comma === false) {
        $str_result .= ' ';
        $comma = true;
    } else {
        $str_result .= ', ';
        $comma = false;
    }
}

echo $str_result;
```

It uses a boolean that is set to true and false every run so only every other word the comma is shown.

Comment: Amazing! You Saved me Now! Thanks so much! Cheers.